# Problem with useEffect and navbar active on scroll "To fix, cancel all subscriptions"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I'm trying to make active anchors in navbar navigation on scroll. Everything is working until I don't change page and return back to home page, then when I scroll page I get an error from useEffect hook " Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. " How I should cancel all subscriptions ?

useEffect code :

```
const [headerText, setHeader] = useState(false);
let mount = false;    
useEffect(() => {
  if (!mount) {
    scrollActiveNav();
    scrollStickyNav((header) => {
      setHeader(header);
    });
  }
  return () => {
    mount = true;
  };
}, []);
```

Sticky navbar function :

```
const scrollStickyNav = (cb) => {
  const scrollSticky = window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const header = document.getElementById("navbar");    
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 80) {
      header.classList.add("navbar-sticky");
      header.classList.remove("absolute");
      cb(true);
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("navbar-sticky");
      header.classList.add("absolute");
      cb(false);
    }
  });
  return window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollSticky);
}
```

Acitve link anchor in navabar function:

```
const scrollActiveNav = () => {
  const activeNav = window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const options = {
      threshold: 0.5
    };
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        const id = entry.target.id;
        if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
          document.querySelector(`.navbar-nav li a[href="${id}"]`).classList.add('active');
        } else {
          document.querySelector(`.navbar-nav li a[href="${id}"]`).classList.remove('active');
        }
      });
    }, options);
    document.querySelectorAll('section[id]').forEach((section) => {
      observer.observe(section);
    });
  });
  return window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", activeNav);
}
```

Comment: There are a few things going wrong here, 1st your not removing any events, your using `window.removeEventListener` wrong,  you have to make sure the event function you remove is the same as the one you added.   Also the place you want to remove them is were you currently have `mount = true;`, that is kind of ironic, as that's when it's unmounted.. :)

Comment: @Keith So when i return window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", activeNav); is not working can you explain why ? with mount = true I just wrote for the test.

Comment: Because -> `const activeNav = window.addEventListener`  ,  activeNav will be `undefined`..  More details on how to use `addEventListener` here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @Keith Right thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try change this line let mount = false; for this const mount = useRef(false).

```
const [headerText, setHeader] = useState(false);
let mount = useRef(false); 
   
useEffect(() => {
  if (!mount.current) {
    scrollActiveNav();
    scrollStickyNav((header) => {
      setHeader(header);
    });
    mount.current = true;
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Not working, the same "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

Comment: Did you try to remove the event listener window.addEventListener("scroll"..., when component is destroyed?

Comment: When I remove  scrollStickyNav((header) => {
      setHeader(header);
    }); is not error so i think problem is with useState or this function

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do something like this?

```
useEffect(() => {
 scrollActiveNav();
 const activeNav = window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const options = {
      threshold: 0.5
    };
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        const id = entry.target.id;
        if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
          document.querySelector(`.navbar-nav li a[href="${id}"]`).classList.add('active');
        } else {
          document.querySelector(`.navbar-nav li a[href="${id}"]`).classList.remove('active');
        }
      });
    }, options);
    document.querySelectorAll('section[id]').forEach((section) => {
      observer.observe(section);
    });
  });

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", activeNav);
  };
}, []);
```